# Write mysql query in html select field

Tags: html

e.g

```
<select><option>Price</option></select>

$sql=mysql_query("SELECT `rug_catagory_id` , `rug_price`                            
FROM `rugs_all_data`                            
WHERE `rug_catagory_id` =1                            
ORDER BY `rug_price` ASC                           
LIMIT 0 , 30") or die(mysql_error());
```

i want to click "price" option field than run this query..
guide me about this ??                           };

Comment: Hey folks, be so kind as to tell OP, why you downvoted at least. He is a newbie! I guess it is the use of mysql_*-functions, the unprecise question and the missing code formatting ... But is that a reason not to comment at all?

Comment: please don't downvote a newbie..rather tell him about the mistake he did

Answer (score 1):

Use Javascript to identify the option selected event and use ajax to call your sever side e.g php and from php perform your db operations and show the result in the front end

HTML

```
<form>
  <select class="target">
    <option value="price" selected="selected">Price</option>
    <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

JS

```
$( ".target" ).change(function() {
  //use ajax call to server page
$.ajax({
  url: "test.php",//pass data to php and do all db stuffs
  context: document.body
}).done(function() {//callback function
  //do operations on success
});
});
```

PHP

```
//get form data
//open mysql connection
//query db
//return result
```

Comment: This answer is not helping him, seriously, you should post answers in lil detail...

Comment: please look into updated post Mr. Alien

Comment: Well, still, but better than the previous one, will upvote :) but keep improving them..

Answer (score 1):

When click on the price option write that code using jQuery

```
$('document').ready(function(){
     $("#price").click(function(){
             $.post(
                    "price.php",function(result){
                          alert(resule)
                     }
              );
     });
});
```

now write that query into price.php file and echo price you get that price into result.